# How to make a Binding when DataContext is already set

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datacontext

I have a custom `UserControl` of which I am setting the `DataContext` as a binding to some object. I also want to enable or disable the control based on a binding to a boolean in the parent object. This however fails, cause as soon as the data context is set, the system tries to find all other bindings in the new data context instead of the old one. (This seems a bit weird to me anyway.)

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name;
}

public class Zoo
{
    public Zoo ()
    {
        AnimalOnDisplay = new AnimalOnDisplay { Name = "Tyrannosaurus" };
    }

     public bool ZooIsClosed;
     public Animal AnimalOnDisplay;
}

static void Main()
{
    ZooUserControl control = new ZooUserControl ();
    control.DataContext = new Zoo();
    control.Show();
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProgramme.ZooUserControl"
             xmlns:zoo="clr-namespace:Zoo.UserControls">
    <StackPanel>

        <Label Content="Welcome!" />
        <zoo:AnimalUserControl DataContext="{Binding AnimalOnDisplay}"
                               IsEnabled="{Binding ZooIsClosed}" />

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The `DataContext` of the above user control is a valid instance of `Zoo` (I checked this). This gives the following error:

```
 System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ZooIsClosed' property not found on 'object' ''Animal`1' (HashCode=44290843)'. 
                                 BindingExpression:Path=ZooIsClosed; DataItem='Animal`1' (HashCode=44290843); target element is 'AnimalUserControl' (Name=''); 
                                 target property is 'IsEnabled' (type 'Boolean')
```

So clearly, it's looking for `ZooIsClosed` in the wrong place. I tried to bind it to the current `DataContext` like this:

```
 IsEnabled="{Binding ZooIsClosed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

which produces the same error, and with an `ElementName`, which didn't work either.

How can I bind it to the correct variable (i.e. the `ZooIsClosed` in `Zoo`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Binding` for the `IsEnabled` by using `RelativeSource` tracking up to the `UserControl` like this:

```
<zoo:AnimalUserControl DataContext="{Binding AnimalOnDisplay}"
         IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.ZooIsClosed,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Note the `Path` is set to `DataContext.ZooIsClosed`.

Also your model is not properly written (I hope it's just demonstrative).

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! (I know, the model is demonstrative, wasn't tested and undoubtedly contains errors, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is asked the binding to search for a property called `ZooIsClosed` on your AnimalOnDisplay property. We can see from your code behind that this relationship does not exist.

Because both `ZooIsClosed` and `AnimalOnDisplay` are properties of your `Zoo` class, so what you should do is set your DataContext to your `Zoo` class instance (assuming your ZooControl has a Zoo instance DependencyProperty), then bind to properties on that instance, i.e. `IsZooClosed` and `AnimalOnDisplay`.

Here is a bit of code to get you started, see if it fits your needs:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProgramme.ZooUserControl"
         xmlns:zoo="clr-namespace:Zoo.UserControls"
         DataContext="{Binding Zoo.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type zoo:ZooControl}}}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="Welcome!" />
        <zoo:AnimalUserControl IsEnabled="{Binding ZooIsClosed}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: You're right, my question was unclear/incomplete. I editted it: the `DataContext` of the user control is a valid instance of the `Zoo` class. Now the problem is a bit clearer: `AnimalUserControl` needs a different `DataContext`, but `IsEnabled` should still bind to the current one.